# Inlining java code using eclipse jdt/ast

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm trying to inline java method using eclipse jdt/ast.

For example, I'd like to make this code

```
class Hello {
    static void hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello();
        System.out.println("z");
        hello();
        System.out.println("h");
        hello();
    }
}
```

into this.

```
class Hello {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("z");
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println("h");
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

I could get the body block of hello() method stored in `Block bl`.

I also have the body block of main() method stored in `Block block`, and I could delete hello(); `ExpressionStatement`s in the block.

Then, I need to insert the `Block bl` to where the `hello();` is invoked.
I tried

```
block.statements().add(position, bl.getAST());
```

and

```
block.statements().add(position, bl);
```

where `position` is the location of `hello()` method in statements(), but both of them raises an error.

What might be wrong? As `Block` is `Statement`, I guess one can insert `Block` in `Block#statements()`.

[image]

## ADDED

Based on sevenforce answer, I could get the block inserted, but I have the `{` and `}` included.

```
class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    System.out.println("z");
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    System.out.println("h");
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to remove them?

### ADDED2

With this code:

```
ASTNode singleStmt = (ASTNode) bl.statements().get(0);
block.statements().add(position, ASTNode.copySubtree(bl.getAST(), singleStmt));
```

It shows only the first statement in `hello()` method. For example, with

```
static void hello() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    System.out.println("hello2");
}
```

I have only `System.out.println("hello");` inlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons for `add` throwing an exception.
Normally the specific exception should give you a hint. E.g. the node to be added must be in the same `AST`.

In your case I'd guess, that you attempt to add the same `block` object, which is already used in the `MethodDeclaration` node of `hello()` and each node is allowed to have just one parent.

A possible solution to that is copying the node:

```
block.statements().add(position, ASTNode.copySubtree(bl.getAST(), bl));
```

---

For extracting single statements the following should work:

```
ASTNode singleStmt = (ASTNode) bl.statements().get(0);
block.statements().add(position, ASTNode.copySubtree(bl.getAST(), singleStmt));
```

---

To add all statements from the block you can just loop over:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bl.statements().size(); i++) {
     ASTNode singleStmt = (ASTNode) bl.statements().get(i);
     block.statements().add(position + i,
         ASTNode.copySubtree(bl.getAST(), singleStmt));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and it works. However, I got { and } included in the code. I updated the post.

Comment: Your added comment works, except one thing: not statements.get(0), but statements().get(0);

Comment: One more question. I updated the question. Could you care to check? Thanks.

Comment: For your method of looping over, it shouldn't be working when the statement has blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding to the block you might think of replacing the method invocation.

```
final ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(compilationUnit.getAST());

rewriter.replace(methodInvocationNode, blockNode, null);
```